# How do I keep my consumer listening the messages on Azure Sevice Bus using Azure sdk for Golang v0.3.1?

Tags: azure, go, azureservicebus

I've been using the module azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/messaging/azservicebus v0.3.1 to connect my consumer with Azure Service Bus but the code implemented only receive a fixed number of message and then stop the application and I'would like to keep the consumer listening the queue. Follow my code:

```
    client, err := azservicebus.NewClientFromConnectionString("Connection String", nil)
    
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create Service Bus Client: %s", err.Error())
    }

    receiver, err := client.NewReceiverForQueue("queue", nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create Consumer: %s", err.Error())
    }

    messages, err := receiver.ReceiveMessages(context.TODO(), 10, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to receive Messages: %s", err.Error())
    }

    for _, message := range messages {

        body, err := message.Body()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to parse message body: %s", err.Error())
        }

        fmt.Println("Message --->", string(body))

        err = receiver.CompleteMessage(context.TODO(), message)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to complete message: %s", err.Error())
        }

        fmt.Printf("Received and completed message\n")

    }
```

Comment: Then, don't you have to call `messages, err := receiver.ReceiveMessages(context.TODO(), 10, nil)` more than once?

Comment: I wouldn't want to put the for {} in the code . I would really like to leave the responsability to sdk module.

Answer (score 2):

You have 99% of the code - as you noted `ReceiveMessages` only returns the amount you requested.

So you just want to wrap your logic in a loop so you can run it continually:

```golang
for {
    messages, err := receiver.ReceiveMessages(context.TODO(), 10, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to receive Messages: %s", err.Error())
    }

    for _, message := range messages {
        body, err := message.Body()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to parse message body: %s", err.Error())
        }

        fmt.Println("Message --->", string(body))

        err = receiver.CompleteMessage(context.TODO(), message)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to complete message: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, [0.3.2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/releases/tag/sdk%2Fmessaging%2Fazservicebus%2Fv0.3.2) was just released and it contains some fixes that you'll be interested in as they do affect ReceiveMessages.

Comment: Also, @danielfarrell had the right answer but I apparently don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: I wouldn't want to put the ```for {}``` in the code . I would really like to leave the responsability to sdk module.

Comment: @RafaelReis,  it doesn't make sense for the API to do the flow control.  Polling a queue is an indefinite operation.  You are the only one who knows when that for loop will end, and when to iterate, and what the innards of the loop will be.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I desagree, fallow an example in nodejs using the Azure message broker:



`import { ServiceBusClient } from '@azure/service-bus'

export default async (config) => ServiceBusClient
 .createFromConnectionString(config.connection)
 .createQueueClient(config.queueName)
 .createReceiver(config.receiveMode)
 .registerMessageHandler(config.handler, config.errorHandler)`
The azure sdk is responsible to do "polling" in the queue. When arrive some message the handler is called.

Comment: Sure, in async nodejs land, everything is a callback.  Hey, if you can find the SDK support for it, for Go SDK, Great!  I don't see it but maybe I missed it!

Comment: @DanielFarrell no problem! Thanks for help me!

Comment: So is it a good solution to call a function/task in a goroutine that will run the infinite loop for receiving and processing the messages from service bus? 
I also initially thought this approach is bad as coming from event-driven programming(Node JS), but since go uses routine and internally this is the same implementation at the root machine code level. @RafaelReis

Comment: You'll want your loop running somewhere. If the message processing is all your app does then having the main loop of your app actually just be the `for {}` is a really easy way to get an app that doesn't terminate without much work.

Having a separate goroutine can also work well. For instance, if you want to do message processing but you are also doing some other work and you don't want to block your main thread.

Comment: @RichardPark I had to use goroutine as my app was a microservice with API hosted and then this message processing was needed there. 
Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Just a quick question on the `for {}` I seem to have a situation where after leaving it overnight, messages are no longer being picked up by the running process.  Any thoughts on the best way to ensure that we're still connected?

Comment: @darren, there have been quite a few fixes in very recent package releases. If you're still having issues you can file an issue in our github repo and we can work from there.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/new/choose